# Gamemaker 1.4 android build.gradle edit

Tags: game-maker

I spent much time by making my android game and i have problem now.
I cant upload it to playstore because of 64 requipment. I have readed i could add this line to build.gradle

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

Could you help me please with adding this to gradle.build?
i have found that file in Roaming\GameMaker-Studio\Android\runner\RootFiles
This is content of the file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0+'

    }
}

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
```

im not sure if this is correct file, tried adding this line bud has error while compiling.
Or maybe you know diffrent way to do this.
I am using GMS 1.4

Answer (score 0):

I've been checking different ways to make 1.4 to generate a 64-bit compatible apk file but even if you achieve to add arm-v8a and x86_64 so Gradle try to generate it, it still needs libyoyo.so (and maybe others) compatible files for each of your new abis to make a 64bits android compatible apk.
The only way to get those files is to have the source code and cross-compile it for each of the 64-bit required abis.